# Clearing markers based on zoom, inside function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having lots of trouble trying to clear the markers. When the user zooms the map out beyond  certain point. However I was unable to remove the marker. Here is what I have tried so far.

```
 var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
var ZoomMarker;

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'mousemove', function() {
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    zoomLevel = map.getZoom();




    if (zoomLevel >= 15) {
        for (var i = 0; i < Zoomed_in.length; i++) {

            ZoomMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(Zoomed_in[i][1], Zoomed_in[i][2]),
                map: map,
            });
        }
        zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < ZoomMarker.length; i++) {

            ZoomMarker[i].setMap(null);
            ZoomMarker.pop();
        }




    }

});
});
```

I don't want to make a global function for removing all markers since I have other markers which are called on map initialisation. I have tried to use https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove
to remove the markers, however it does not seem to work. I presume this is due to the markers being in an array. This is why I am using the for loop to on the removal of the array.

Is there a way I can do:

```
ZoomMarker= new Object();
```

To destroy the array in effect removing it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality isn't creating an array it is just overwriting the ZoomMarker object.

```
  ZoomMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(Zoomed_in[i][1], Zoomed_in[i][2]),
                map: map,
            });
```

Instead try this :

```
 ZoomMarker.push( new google.maps.Marker({
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(Zoomed_in[i][1], Zoomed_in[i][2]),
            map: map,
        });


 // assuming you make ZoomMarker = [];
```

*EDIT*:

I mentioned you need to make ZoomMarker an Array thats why push doesn't work.

```
var ZoomMarker = [];
```

This is exactly how the example is set that you cited.

```
var markers = [];
```

Comment: That does not seem to work with my full script I think it is the .push part.